# adjusting screen brightness Skylake+Nvidia

Tags: nvidia, brightness, intel, nvidia-optimus

I have a Santech T67 which is a laptop based on Clevo P640RE. Briefly, the hardware is:

- Intel Skylake CPU (i7-6700HQ)
- Nvidia GTX 970m (NVIDIA Corporation GM204M [GeForce GTX 970M] (rev a1), from `lspci`)
- Intel HD530 (Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics (rev 06), from `lspci`)

I managed to get Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 working by appending `idle=nomwait nouveau.modeset=0` to the kernel boot parameters.
Now everything seems to work kinda fine (excluding the power consumption which is very high. ~1h15m when on Win10 I get ~2h50m). I'm using `nvidia-prime` with `nvidia-364` drivers.
The problem I have is that the brigthness keys are not working. I have to use the slider on the top right corner if I want to change the screen brightness, and this is kinda annoying.
I tried adding `acpi_osi=vendor` but it didn't work. Any other suggestion?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try seeing if Xorg is detecting the keys as brightness changers.

Use `evtest` to see what the currently pressed key is reported as:
    `sudo evtest`
Select the number of your keyboard's input (ie. /dev/input4, you'd select 4)
Then try pressing your buttons, it should return something similar to this:
`Event: time 1459134230.421349, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------`
`Event: time 1459134230.526008, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value f8`
`Event: time 1459134230.526008, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 225 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP), value 0`
If the buttons are reported as something different, then you can just add the buttons as custom shortcuts in the Settings menu. The commands to raise and lower brightness are `xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessUp` and `xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessDown` respectively.

Also another random question, how did you get the nvidia-364 drivers to install and work correctly on your laptop? Everytime I try to install them on mine (i7-6700HQ and GTX970M same as you) it whines about not finding a compatible driver in the Xorg logs (it gets stuck in the login loop)

Comment: According to evtest the brightness buttons are not reported :-/

I have added the drivers from the graphics-drivers ppa, I have installed them with apt and then I have rebooted. Didn't have any problem at all on the graphic side...but my headphones are not working with kernel 4.4 I have to use 4.5 but with this last one the video cards  fans are running at maximum :( this skylake is total s......

Comment: So evtest isn't detecting the buttons at all or is it just detecting them as something else? And yeah every time I try to install the nVidia drives from the graphics-drivers ppa something goes wrong, so I'm just using nouveau and Linux 4.6 to get 3D acceleration with nouveau.

Comment: evtest is not detecting the buttons at all :( regarding the video card I honestly have no idea. It seems that skylake+gtx 970m have different problems and different solutions for everyone :-/ 

Dunno if this may be useful to you but I'm using ubuntu gnome 16.04 and I only have `idle=nomwait` inside `/etc/default/grub`...

Comment: Oh hm, IDK whats up with that then. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post, but I have the P640RE and it's working really well (almost perfectly) with Kubuntu 18.04. In case someone is still searching for this info, here's what I did:

1. Immediately after install, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> the moment you see the login screen (if you delay for too long, the system will freeze)
2. `sudo vi /etc/default/grub` (or use whatever editor you're used to).
3. Change the `GRUB_CMDLINE_DEFAULT` so it looks like this: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi='!Windows 2015'"`
4. Run: `sudo update-grub`
5. Reboot

I installed the Nvidia driver using:

```
sudo ubuntu-driver autoinstall
```

I then created file `/etc/modprobe.d/zz-nvidia.conf` with the following contents to prevent screen tearing:

```
andy@p640re:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/zz-nvidia.conf 
options nvidia_drm modeset=1
```

Then run: `sudo update-initramfs -u`.

To switch to Intel GPU mode to save power: `sudo prime-select intel` (then reboot). When idle, power consumption is around 10W (compared to around 26W when the Nvidia GPU is powered on). To turn the Nvidia GPU back on: `sudo prime-select nvidia` (then reboot).

My brightness keys work as expected.